# Get user's input and use it as a Function

Tags: javascript, node.js, web

I am working on a test case visualizer where the user can run his code and check if it is correct. I'm using Node Js and I'm getting user's code from a text-area. Assuming that this is what I'm getting from the user:

```
function add(x, y) {
    return x + y;
}
```

And this is what I'm doing at the backend:

```
app.post("/main", function(req, res) {
    console.log("hello");
    var x = 1;
    var y = 2;
    req.body.code //missing
})
```

How can I use this input as a function and run it to get the values?

Comment: And then one day, the user sends `while(true);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing is that I used [vm2 sandbox](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vm2)

vm2 is a sandbox that can run untrusted code with whitelisted Node's built-in modules. It works well, and you can limit access to certain methods.

First require it:

```
const { VM } = require('vm2');
```

then, specify the timeout, and the sandbox:

```
const vm = new VM({
    console: 'inherit',
    timeout: 1000,
    sandbox: { global_variable },
    require: {
        external: true,
    },
});
```

global_variable is nothing but a "var" that I used to export the output.

Now let's use the following function in a string named "func":

```
function Main(x,y){
return x+y};
```

concatenate it with:

```
global_variable.exports=Main(5,5);
```

Now run the code via:

```
vm.run("func")
```

To print the answer, just do:

```
global_variable.exports;
```

This solution works only if you have a javascript code that you need to run. I am still looking for other solutions that run for multiple languages in node js.
If you have any suggestions please do let me know.

Answer (score 2):

***Do NOT use `eval()` !!***

Running arbitrary code from a user on your server might be the easiest way I have ever heard of to get hacked. Any user can do anything they want with your server if you do this.

There are numerous parsers (like [esprima](https://esprima.org/)) that can parse/validate the code without actually running it. Go for one of those instead of opening the front door to your server.

Answer (score -2):

The simplest way would be using `eval()` function.
Say, your client passes function as a string to the server (code parameter in body). So you can do this:

**Just a reminder: This method is very unsafe and it's not a good practice to use `eval`, so depending on you situation, you may be able to use other methods**

```
app.post("/main", function(req, res) {
  console.log("hello");
  var x = 1;
  var y = 2;
  eval(req.body.code); // This will return an Error if code is wrong
  add(x,y);
})
```