# How to run user's Python and Java code in Node Js

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

I am creating a test case website to allow students to solve some programming questions and test their code. I am using express and Node Js.

I am planning to add multiple languages such as Javascript, Python, and Java.
For javascript, I was able to use vm2 sandbox to safely run the user's arbitrary code. Go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67759436/get-users-input-and-use-it-as-a-function) to see how I did it.

However, I am still not sure about how to implement it for Java and Python.

For Python, there is the build-in "child_process" that allows running a python script which is basically another python file and allows us to get the output from it. What I want is to get the user's code from a text area and run it inside the app.js file.

Is there any library or sandbox that allows me to do that?

Comment: You can also use [python-shell](https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-shell) package to run Python scripts from Node. And for Java, there's [java](https://www.npmjs.com/package/java).

Comment: yes but this doesn't allow me to run a fully functioning java code right? I would be writing something like: var ArrayList = java.import('java.util.ArrayList');
var list3 = new ArrayList();
list3.addSync('item1');
which is not what the user is going to write